# Compare two different arraylists and get differences java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, compare

I've got two arraylists, and I'm looking for an efficient way to count the number of different values.

Some example lists:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("String A");
    list.add("String B");
    list.add("String C");

List<String> anotherlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("String B");
    list.add("String A");
    list.add("String D");
```

You could do something to check for each item (because the order should not matter) if it is the same or not (pure conceptual):

```
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
             for(int j=0;j<anotherlist.size();j++)
             {
                   if (item.get(i) == item.get(j)){
                       intDifferent = intDifferent+1;
                   } else {
                       intSame = intSame+1;
                   }
                   intTotal = intTotal+1
             }
    }

    //Some calculations with intdifferent en inttotal to find out how many different 
    //values we actually have  between the lists, in the case of the example, it 
    //should output 1
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or is there a sample or post available on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using `Set`s for this.

Drop all the items from one array into a `HashSet` and then loop over the other array checking if it is contained in the `Set`.

This will be much faster than looping over an `ArrayList` each time.

Comment: Please tell him also to compare strings via equals.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose you are correct of course but using my suggestion he doesn't do any comparison himself at all :)

Comment: I know. Hash data structures at its best. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm worst case complexity is O(n* log(n))

```
    // worst case O(nLog(n))
    Collections.sort(l1);
    // worst case O(nLog(n))
    Collections.sort(l2);

    // pointer for l1 list
    int p = 0;

    // pointer for l2 list
    int q = 0;

    int diffCounter = 0;
    // worst case N
    while (true) {

        if (p == l1.size() -1 ) {
            // remainig items in l2 list are diff
            diffCounter += (l2.size() -1) - q;
            break;
        }
        if (q == l2.size() -1 ) {
            diffCounter += (l1.size() - 1) - p;
        }

        int compareResult = l1.get(p).compareTo(l2.get(q));
        if (compareResult > 0) {
            p++;
            diffCounter++;
        } else if (compareResult < 0 ) {
            q++;
            diffCounter++;
        }
```

`